# calling webmethod from jquery C# returning 404 error in .net aspx page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

must be missing something basic here. I am getting a 404 error calling a webmethod from jquery in an aspx page I'm running locally.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="empJquery.aspx.cs" Inherits="webApiOracle.empJquery" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>jquery emps</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {
            getEmployees();

        });

        function getEmployees() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'empJquery.aspx/Test',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    alert("Start!!! ");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("a");
                },
                error: function (msg) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }

            });
        }

    </script>
```

then in the code behind page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using webApiOracle.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


namespace webApiOracle
{
    public partial class empJquery : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string Test()
        {

            return "Success";
        }

    }

}
```

I'm getting a 404 error whenever I run I attempted changing url to  /empJquery.aspx/Test I also tried localhost/empJQuery.aspx/Test and localhost:48784/empJquery.aspx/Test  but I can't seem to get it. Do I need to add something to my web config? I'm running .net 4.5 
thanks

Comment: Your port number must match the port you're hosting on. But if you get a 404, it means that there's something listening on that port, it just doesn't know where the page is or it's not mapped to a particular resource properly.

Comment: unrelated, `success` is obslete, `.done` is the way to go. please read the **Deprecation Notice** at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: oh ok thanks did not realize success had become obsolete

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I just found it my app is a hybrid `MVC`, `Web API`, `ASPX` solution and my route configs were messing me up so I had to add:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{page}.aspx/{*webmethod}");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is `routes.Ignore("{page}.aspx/{*webmethod}");` anyway